# How to draw a horizontal line at the end of proofs?

Tags: theorems, rules, amsthm

How can I draw a horizontal line at the end of proofs? I use `\begin{proof}....\end{proof}`.

I use `amsthm` package without any modification.

Comment: You can redefine the `QEDsymbol`.

Answer (score 11):

You could patch `\endproof` (the end macro of the `proof` environment) to insert a horizontal rule automatically. The following patch is provided via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsthm,etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endproof}% <cmd>
  {\endtrivlist}% <search>
  {\endtrivlist\par\nobreak\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill}% <replace>
  {}{}% <succes><failure>
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Here is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The patch removes a vertical skip after ending `proof`, and inserts `\nobreak` together with a horizontal rule (`\hrulefill`) so that they are not separated by a page break.

Comment: the designers of `amsthm` don't consider the vertical skip after a proof to be an error, so would prefer "removes" to "corrects".  (the purpose of the skip is to make the end of the proof more obvious; clearly, the rule has the same intent, and is handled appropriately in your code.)

Answer (score 8):

Here's another option, this time using the [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package as a front-end for `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
numbered=no,
headfont=\normalfont\itshape,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
prefoothook=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}\endgraf\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\def\qed{\hrulefill}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}
2+2=4.
\qed
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Other option is to use `\def\qed{\rule{.75\linewidth}{1pt}}` so it is possible to set up the width of the line and the thickness.