# Is there a way to modify the theorem environment in order to have an horizontal rule immediately before and immediately after the statement?

Tags: theorems, rules, newtheorem, addlines

I've just seen this solution for the *proof* environment and I really liked it.

[How to draw a horizontal line at the end of proofs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109317/how-to-draw-a-horizontal-line-at-the-end-of-proofs)

I'm wondering if is there an elegant way to do it also with the theorem environment.

**Note**
I don't want to use boxes or mdframed packages...

---

Edit: the following code for example doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \usepackage{thmtools} 
    \usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath]{ntheorem}
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule\vspace{-1.5ex}\leavevmode\nobreak}%\leavevmode
    \theorempostwork{\vspace*{-1ex}\hrule\bigskip\leavevmode}
    \theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
    \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
    \theoremseparator{. }
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{thm}[D’Alembert-Gauss]
    The field $\mathbf C$ is algebraically closed.
    \end{thm}
    \lipsum[2]

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Theorems}
 \listoftheorems[ignoreall,onlynamed={thm,lmm,prop}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple with the  `\theoremprework` and `\theorempostwork` commands from `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath]{ntheorem}%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule\vspace{-1.5ex}\leavevmode\nobreak}%\leavevmode
\theorempostwork{\vspace*{-1ex}\hrule\bigskip\leavevmode}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{. }
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\bigskip

\lipsum[1]
\begin{thm}[D’Alembert-Gauss]
The field $\mathbf C$ is algebraically closed.
\end{thm}
\lipsum[2]
\bigskip
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Theorems}
\theoremlisttype{allname}
\listtheorems{thm}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The rules can get detached at page breaks and there's no spacing around the statement.

Comment: @egreg: For the rules at page breaks,  there must be a way to avoid them that's explained somewhere  in the documentation, but I can't find it. What do you mean with ‘no spacing around the statement’? I added a small negative vertical space because I found the spacing at the end too large.Could you give some details?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate answer! Anyway this way strangely collides with the command `\listoftheorems` of the package `thmtools`... Lualatex starts compiling the document but a certain point it get stuck and I have to force it it stop with the terminal.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: It seems `\listoftheorems` conflicts with the `\listtheorems` command from `ntheorem`, for some reason. I'll post an example with the code from ntheorem.