# How do I create a problem command with horizontal lines on the top and the bottom

Tags: macros

I need some help creating a problem command that formats it in the way I'm looking for. I've settled on a way to format my problems for homeworks and have been doing it mostly manually and copypasting for now, but it would be more convenient to have a command I could use. Ideally I want my problems to look something like this:
[image]

With accompanying code ideally looking something like

```
    \problem{Problem 1 -- Evaluation Map}{
        Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces with $Y$ Banach, and let $\varnothing \neq U \subseteq X$ be open.  
        Define the evaluation map $E : C^1_b(U;Y) \times U \to Y$ via $E(f,x) = f(x)$.  Prove that $E$ is $C^1$. 
    }
```

i.e. `\problem{problem title}{problem statement}`. However, I am having trouble making the command in that way. I tried something like

```
\newcommand{\problem}[2]{
\hline
\vspace{0.1in}
\textbf{#1}\\
{#2}\\
\vspace{0.1in}
\hline
}
```

but this was throwing some errors and it had some issues with alignment at the end - if I was in the `\[\]` math mode at the end, then the space at the end would be too much. If I get rid of the vspace, then the space is not enough. Could anybody give me some assistance?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396485/110998 for an approach for adding such lines. You might want to define your problems as a "Theorem".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `\hrule`, not `\hline`; the latter is used in `tabular`s. You could define your command as

```
\newcommand{\problem}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hrule
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \textbf{#1}\\
  #2%
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \hrule
  \par
}
```

However, beware of spurious spaces, in the definition of the command as well as when using it. It might be better to define an environment.

```
\newenvironment{Problem}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hrule
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \textbf{#1}\\
}{%
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \hrule
  \par
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\problem}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hrule
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \textbf{#1}\\
  #2%
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \hrule
  \par
}

\newenvironment{Problem}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \hrule
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \textbf{#1}\\
}{%
  \vskip-\lastskip
  \par\vspace{0.1in}\noindent
  \hrule
  \par
}
 

\begin{document}
\problem{Problem 1 -- Evaluation Map}{
  Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed
  vector spaces with $Y$ Banach, and let
  $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq X$ be open.  Define the evaluation map
  $E : C^1_b(U;Y) \times U \to Y$ via $E(f,x) = f(x)$.  Prove that $E$
  is $C^1$.
}
\bigskip


\begin{Problem}{Problem 1 -- Evaluation Map}
  Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces with $Y$ Banach, and let
  $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq X$ be open.  Define the evaluation map
  $E : C^1_b(U;Y) \times U \to Y$ via $E(f,x) = f(x)$.  Prove that
  $E$ is $C^1$.
\end{Problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. This does work better, but I think I still have the problem with the display math adding an extra space at the end. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: @SubhasishMukherjee I have modified my answer.

Comment: You don;t need `\par\noindent` with `\hrule`.  You might need a `\vskip` before and/or after to add some space.  `\hrule` does not use either `\baselineskip` or `\lineskip`.

Comment: How does this work at page breaks? I have a similar set-up,  coded as an environment, but ended up fitting it in a minipage. That is to avoid having the rule on one page and the rest on the other, or even the rule and the title on one page and the rest on an other one. This has the drawback that sometimes you get enormous blank spaces at the end of a page. I think that it could be solved by implementing the functionality of sectioning commands. No idea how to do that, though